# modalpopupExtender with dropdown Bootstrap using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using modalpopupExtender but problem is i need data in dropdown list with responsive so can i create modalpopupextender with bootstrap. If possible please  send me code using asp.net

Comment: This link might help you, http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/42R0171112-CRUD-Operations-using-jQuery-dialog,-Entity-Framework-and-ASP.NET-MVC.html